# Requests and Requests-toolbelt on Windows throws UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, python-requests

This code works well between unix servers, but when the client is Windows, the server consistently throws a UnicodeDecodeError, as per the stack trace below.  I cannot figure out why requests is trying to decode a file object.  It seems like `temp_file` on the Windows client takes on a different form and is therefore encoded differently when the request reaches the server.  Any clues would be awesome.

```
# client-side (Windows) - some code omitted for brevity

temp_file = TemporaryFile()
temp_file.write(file.read(chunk_size))
temp_file.seek(0)
payload = MultipartEncoder(
    {'uploadedFile': (path, temp_file, 'application/octet-stream'),
    'position': str(position), 'chunk_size': str(chunk_size),
    'chunk_number': str(chunk_number)})
r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers={'Content-Type': payload.content_type})
temp_file.close()


# server-side (Unix)

@view_config(route_name='remote.agent_upload', renderer='json')
def remote_agent_upload(request):
    r = request.response
    uploadedFile = request.POST['uploadedFile']  # ERROR HERE
    chunk_size = request.POST['chunk_size']
    chunk_number = request.POST['chunk_number']
    position = request.POST['position']
    fs = uploadedFile.file
    filename = uploadedFile.filename
    fs.seek(0)
    path = os.path.join(agent.root, os.path.basename(filename))
    # remove the file if it exists
    if chunk_number == '0' and os.path.isfile(path):
        os.remove(path)
    f = open(path, 'a+b')
    f.seek(int(position))
    f.write(fs.read())
    fs.close()
    f.close()
return r

# relevant section of traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/Volumes/Extra/Repos/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/views.py", line 501, in _requestonly_view
    response = view(request)
  File "/Volumes/Extra/Repos/bang/bang/remote_api.py", line 393, in remote_agent_upload
    uploadedFile = request.POST['uploadedFile']
  File "/Volumes/Extra/Repos/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/request.py", line 807, in POST
    vars = MultiDict.from_fieldstorage(fs)
  File "/Volumes/Extra/Repos/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/multidict.py", line 92, in from_fieldstorage
    obj.add(field.name, decode(value))
  File "/Volumes/Extra/Repos/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webob/multidict.py", line 78, in <lambda>
    decode = lambda b: b.decode(charset)
  File "/Volumes/Extra/Repos/env/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xba in position 3: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Tracing through the `multidict` code this means the file object has no `filename` field set.

Comment: I'd say you need to look closely at the value of `path` in your client-side code. What does `print(repr(path))` produce?

Comment: Hmm you're onto it.  Looks like I need to clear up the Windows path for proper decoding?  `u'W:\\\\the_dir\\the_file.mpg'`

Comment: That looks okay, but I wonder if you need to split off the basename there; `os.path.basename(path)`. A little out of time right now to verify that the value is encoded into a header. At any rate, because on the Pyramid side the `filename` attribute is *empty or completely missing* the object is not treated as a file and an attempt is made to decode the data.

Comment: Gotcha, that's a great headstart - thank you.

Comment: I don't really understand why the basename worked over the filename, but it does - thank you Martjin.

Comment: Where there any non-ASCII characters in the path anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyramid is trying to treat your field as a regular non-file POST field, which means it wants to decode the field value. It treats it as such because there is no filename, or the filename is empty.

Tripple-check your `path` variable on your upload. Make sure it is a base name (no directory names allowed), and not empty:

```
payload = MultipartEncoder(
    {'uploadedFile': (os.path.basename(path), temp_file, 'application/octet-stream'),
    'position': str(position), 'chunk_size': str(chunk_size),
    'chunk_number': str(chunk_number)})
```